# Dataframe merge by row

Tags: pandas

I have two pd df and I want to merge df2 to each row of df1 based on the ID in df1. The final df should look like in df3.

How do I do it? I tried merge, join and concat and didn't get want I wanted.

```
    df1

      ID  Division 
      1     10
      2      2 
      3      4   
      ...  ...


   df2 

     Product type  Level 
       1            0
       1            1 
       1            2
       2            0
       2            1
       2            2
       2            3 


     df3
       ID   Product type Level    Division
       1      1            0          10
       1      1            1          10
       1      1            2          10
       1      2            0          10
       1      2            1          10
       1      2            2          10
       1      2            3          10
       and repeat for ID 2 and ......
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are looking for a Cartesian product of two dataframes. The following approach should achieve what you want,

```
(df1.assign(key=1)
    .merge(df2.assign(key=1))
    .drop('key', axis=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider such an option:

- set index in both DataFrames to *0*,
- perform an outer join (on indices, so the result is just the Cartesian
  product),
- reset index.

The code to do it is:

```
df1.index = [0] * df1.index.size
df2.index = [0] * df2.index.size
result = df1.join(df2, how='outer').reset_index(drop=True)
```